# How to use multiple variables for xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find element by xpath that contains multiple variables and click on it.

I tried using :

```
oddsnumber = "1.18"
oddstype = "Barcelona"
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@span='"+ oddstype +"' and @span='"+ oddsnumber +"']"))).click()
```

With only one variable it works, but I need to use multiple in order for script to click on right element.

This is the element it should click on

```
<div class="gl-Participant gl-Participant_General gl-Market_General-cn3 "><span class="gl-Participant_Name">Barcelona</span><span class="gl-Participant_Odds">1.18</span></div>
     <span class="gl-Participant_Name">Barcelona</span>
     <span class="gl-Participant_Odds">1.18</span>
```

Tried to make a script that clicks on element by xpath that matches to multiple variables

Comment: what do you mean with "element that contains multiple variables"?

Comment: The element has 2 spans, one contains 'oddsnumber' and the other one contains 'oddstype' in it and I want to find that element by using 2 variables and click on it.

Comment: @JakeM, You would like to identify `div` with  multiple `span` elements reference right?

Comment: Yes, thats what i would like to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this xpath, which targets a `div` element having two `span` children with the requested attributes

```
f"//div[child::span[text()='{oddsnumber}'] and span[text()='{oddstype}']]"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked I only changed '1.18' and 'Barcelona' into '"+ oddsnumber +"' and '"+ oddstype +"' as the value changes often so I can't use text.

Comment: @JakeM Good! You can also use the notation `f"...{var1}...{var2}..."` see updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the update, code looks a lot cleaner that way